# Aborting ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax

Let`s say I am making 2 AJAX requests which are canceled by the user via js:

```
currentRequest.abort();
```

Both requests should have edited a file.
After the second cancel, the first request is taken into account (even if it was aborted).

PHP:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true); 
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    sleep(10);
} else {
    sleep(3);
}
if (connection_aborted () != 0) {
    die(); // if the request was canceled
} else {
    //do magic
}
```

Does it have to do with an Apache config?

I have to do this because I want to simulate a server delay, any ideas to stop the previous request?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/446594/ ?

Comment: Yes, I abort the connection as in the suggested post...

Comment: Also looked up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524203/php-auto-kill-a-script-if-the-http-request-is-cancelled-closed