# SSE isn't disconnecting with use of ignore_user_abort() and connection_aborted()

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I've taken an SSE example from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) and noticed using `Dev Tools` that it kept creating a new connection. Looking at a blog from [Kevin Choppin](https://kevinchoppin.dev/blog/server-sent-events-in-php) I modified the `W3 Schools` example to use a `while(true)` along with both `ignore_user_abort()` and `connection_aborted()`. Using `Dev Tools` I can now see one persistent connection, but when I close the tab or close the browser, I do not see `connection_aborted()' returning true.

SSE Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

ignore_user_abort(true);
while (true) {
  if (connection_aborted()) {
    file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "help");
    exit();
  }

  $time = date('r');
  echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
  flush();

  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Note that if I move the `file_put_contents()` above the `connection_aborted()` check, the file gets written successfully. So it is not a permission issue.

I noticed there is a `connection_status()` function. So I instead modified the code to use a switch case to show the status.

SSE Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

ignore_user_abort(true);
while (true) {
    switch (connection_status()) {
      case CONNECTION_ABORTED:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_ABORTED");
        break;
      case CONNECTION_NORMAL:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_NORMAL");
        break;
      case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT");
        break;
      case __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  $time = date('r');
  echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
  flush();

  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

With this code the file is constantly being wrote to and I am receiving `CONNECTION_NORMAL` as my output.

```
ls -l /tmp/test ; cat /tmp/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 <user> <user> 17 Jan 18 11:09 /tmp/test
CONNECTION_NORMAL
```

The connection isn't aborting and I'm having a hard time figuring out why. I am using `Microsoft Edge` for my browser, but also tried both `Chrome` and `Firefox`. I've also completely closed the browser and used `Task Manager` to kill the process. It's been 20 minutes and still the timestamp is updating with `CONNECTION_NORMAL`.

As for the client code that runs in the browser, it's the same as the `W3 Schools` example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Regarding the backend, the server is running `apache`.

Some more information after seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381270/php-connection-aborted-not-working-correctly) by @JS_Riddler. My understanding of this is that PHP may not abort the connection even with a flush() if the output is buffered. I added the while loop with the `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` with no success. Also I copied the exact example with the `DestructTester` class and the output was the same regardless of whether `ignore_user_abort()` was set to `true` or not. Each print was `NO`.

SSE Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

ignore_user_abort(true);
while (true) {
    switch (connection_status()) {
      case CONNECTION_ABORTED:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_ABORTED");
        break;
      case CONNECTION_NORMAL:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_NORMAL");
        break;
      case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT");
        break;
      case __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__:
        file_put_contents("/tmp/test", "__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  $time = date('r');
  echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
  while (ob_get_level()){
    ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
  }
  flush();

  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Another update. If on the client side I use `source.close();` it still doesn't detect the connection aborted. I've also tried setting my `output_buffering` to 0 in the `php.ini` with no success. This feels broken.

Comment: Does PHP run as FastCGI or module?

Comment: @Olivier It's running as a module which I verified with phpinfo().